# while ($data = mysql_fetch_array() ) doesnot working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from mysql and show them using while loop. But problem is inside while loop there is always one less data i'm getting.
Suppose there is two row in my db , but using this code i'm getting only one row. First row always  missing. Cant figure out why !  Sharing some of the code.

tried var_dump() , it shows there is right number rows in db

```
 $ddaa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupons ORDER BY id");
    echo mysql_error();
  $data = mysql_fetch_array($ddaa);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ddaa))
  {
echo $data['id'] ;
}
```

Comment: This API is insecure and was deprecated a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching one row before using while loop which you are not using anywhere, thats why you are loosing one row.

```
$ddaa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupons ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ddaa))
{
      echo $data['id'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($ddaa);
```

Comment: I can't see that anything is done here that is different from what @ShakirUzZaman did in the first place

Comment: That line fetches a row and does nothing with it.

Comment: i was losing one row for using that line, so removing that line solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

The server and database credentials are missing in your code try this one

```
$server = 'server_name';
$user = 'server_username';
$pass = 'server_password';
$db = 'database_name';

$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

$aa = "SELECT * FROM coupons ORDER BY id"; 
$dd = mysqli_query($connection,$aa); // $connection is the variable which contains server  and database  credentials;
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dd)) {
    echo $data['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It Will Work For Me. Try This...

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("could not connect".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('dbname');
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['firstname'];
    }

    echo "<h3>Record Selected successfully\n</h3>";
    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```